# Disconnected entities with multiple “children reference” to the same already existing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with disconnected entities, when I try to set a reference to the same foreign key for a collection of entities. I write here a simple version of my code (this one is useless, but gives the same error):

```
Prenotazione prenotazione = new Prenotazione();

        prenotazione.Soggiorni = new List<Soggiorno>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Soggiorno soggiorno = new Soggiorno();
            soggiorno.Addebiti = new List<Addebito>();

            prenotazione.Soggiorni.Add(soggiorno);

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                soggiorno.Addebiti.Add(new Addebito { AddebitoID = 1 });
            }
        }

        using (HotelContext context = new HotelContext())
        {
            context.Prenotazioni.Add(prenotazione);

            foreach (Soggiorno soggiorno in prenotazione.Soggiorni)
            {
                foreach (Addebito addebito in soggiorno.Addebiti)
                {
                    context.Entry(addebito).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The strange behavior is about the

Entry(addebito).State

If I use only one "soggiorno" (i.e. in the first for statement I put i < 1) there is no problem at all. But If I need more than one "soggiorno", it gives me the error:

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type Chameleon2.DB.Addebito' have the same primary key value.

Of course they have the same primary key, they must have the same key, because each "soggiorno" has to refer to the same foreign key. I know I can get a similar result with a work around, but I'd like to understand why it doesn’t work. Thanks!

Comment: If `AddebitoID` is the Primary Key of Addebito, then you are trying to add three entities with the same primary key (as the error you posted clearly states). You are in no place in your code setting a Foreign Key (maybe you were looking for `SoggiornoID`?). If your entities are properly connected (let us see your model), then even that should not be necessary.

Comment: Thank for your comment! I don't wont to add new Addebito entities, I need to add a reference to every "soggiorno" that point to an Addebito. For example, if I get the addebito reference with

Addebito addebito = context.Addebiti.Find(1);

inside the scope of DataContext it works perfeclty

Comment: You say you don't want to add new addebitos, but here

`for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                soggiorno.Addebiti.Add(new Addebito { AddebitoID = 1 });
            }
` 
you do exactly that...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got the answer. I write it here, maybe it can be useful to someone else. The problem here is not the duplicated ID of AddebitoID, but the way I was creating the Addebito Object. In order to fix the problem, you have to use two dbContext:

If I had written:

```
    Addebito addebito;
    using (HotelContext context = new HotelContext())
    {
        addebito = context.Addebito.Find(3);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        soggiorno.Addebiti.Add(addebito);
    }
```

everything would have worked perfectly... Lack of experience...